# How can I change my password to what I want it to be?

Tags: support

I just made password recovery for upteenth time in my StackExchange account only because it forces me to:
 - use upper/lower -case letters,
 - use numbers,
 - make it longer then Pi,

Is there a way to make MY OWN PASSWORD be really mine? Because in current state it's impossible to remember not to mention annoying to the very edge of my patience.

Comment: Use http://lastpass.com - also, PI is technically indefinitely long which makes your statement `making it longer than PI` invalid, due to the fact that _my_ password is definitely shorter than PI.

Comment: keypass is also another good tool for password management and doesn't need cloud storage to work.

Comment: SO your answer to bad passwords is to give all your passwords to a 3rd party?  That's a horrible idea.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Or you could go with a local client, like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword). Don't have to worry about a third party, and you can keep all your randomly generated hard passwords in a local encrypted store.

Comment: What Gabe said. I don't want any help remembering my password. I already memorized like 20 passwords and I like them. What I want is being able to use them... And as it is now I can't, because safety measures of Stack Exchange are more insane than the ones my bank use. I'm totally fine with 6-7 letter word as my password here and I couldn't care less for my account on Stack Exchange being hacked.

Comment: While it can indeed be frustrating, all these websites with so many various requirements for passwords, there is a trick to it. Don't look at it as a list of requirements, look at it as a list of modifications to make. Take a word or phrase that meets the length requirement for the site. Then, if capitals are needed, add a capital or two. If numbers or special characters are needed, convert some characters to those. Voila, a password you can remember that meets whatever requirements.

Comment: Since I didn't see your last comment: What I just posted can work for current passwords you have, too. If they need to be longer, add a number of some odd length to the end, assuming they meet all the other requirements. Or, combine two of your old passwords for the length. It can be done! (Note: It's generally advised not to use the same password everywhere, or even in multiple places. Since you mention memorizing and liking a number of passwords, I will assume you use them in various places, which is good practice. Don't let laziness get you in bad habits.)

Comment: @Kendra The problem there is that if you don't remember the requirements, you can't remember the password. And since no site with password format requirements ever reminds you what they are until you're resetting it, it's not possible to reconstruct a password you use only rarely.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Write down the requirements for each site. Done. _That_ can be kept next to your keyboard without fear, unlike an actual list of passwords.

Comment: @Kendra That's horrifying. Reducing attack space is always, always a security problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I never said it was a perfect solution. ;) But if the list of requirements is the problem... (Which, really, shouldn't be- The most you should really need to remember is how long it is. Pretty much every super-strict password set has one upper, one lower, one numeric, and one special, requiring at least three of those four. Past that, it's a matter of length.) Really, I don't even bother with that nonsense- All of my passwords are created with one upper, one lower, one number, and one special character by default. The problem is more creating unique passwords for each site.

Comment: @Kendra I run into this problem frequently due to my particular way of generating passwords, and no, it's not nearly uniform. (Special characters in particular are unpredictable, often banned or restricted in site-specific ways.) Besides, writing it down by your keyboard assumes only one device used in one location, which is unreasonable for most people.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've not run into a site where special characters were banned in recent years, though restrictions I see. Once again, never said it was perfect. Just a way to make things work. (Note: I would never write down a _password itself_ or any sort of seed word and leave it next to a keyboard or whatever. That's just nuts. Site password requirements I could see doing that for if needed, but as I've never had a password generation problem... Not something I do. Therefore, don't care to come up with silly way to have the requirements no matter what.)

Comment: "safety measures of Stack Exchange are more insane than the ones my bank use" That reflects more on your bank than on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 14):

The requirements are not that strict. "1stPassword" will suffice, as will lots and lots of better options.

That said, I strongly recommend not using a password *at all*. If you're already remembering a password for your Google account, Yahoo account or Facebook account, then use those services to log in with instead of SEOpenID - Google in particular has some really nice options for increased security, but the single best reason is simply that *you don't have to remember yet another password.*

If you must create an isolated account here, then register using an email address you're unlikely to lose, use a [GUID](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx) for the password and just reset it whenever you need to log in.

Comment: Well that's kind of what I'm doing right now. But to be honest I expected more of an answer from support member that goes along the lines "let me set the password manually for You and we're done". Because in the end nothing offered here is the solution to an actual problem which is "not letting people make passwords to be whatever they want".

Comment: @NecXelos Although I personally hate password requirements (my passwords are already *quite* secure and memorable without conforming to a silly 1-upper, 1-lower, 1-number, 1-punc scheme, thank you), part of the reason password requirements still exist in the wild is to defeat user attempts to reuse passwords. In other words, what you're wishing to do is exactly why we can't have nice things like freeform passwords.

Comment: @NecXelos Having support personal having any way to either access or set your password is very bad for password security.

Comment: I strongly believe every human being is able to evaluate importance of this-or-another web service in their life and plan password accordingly ranging from "ABCD, because I don't give a damn" to "NoBoDy19CaN28BrEaK37ThIs46PaSsWoRd, because it's my crown jewel". And it should be up to him/her to make that decision. But nvm... Guess I'll just reset my password everytime I need this place.

Comment: @NecXelos Re. "every human being is able to evaluate importance of this-or-another web service in their life and plan password accordingly" People have [consistently](http://datashieldcorp.com/2013/11/24/adobe-data-security-breach-largest-date-highlights-password-protection/) [proven](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2508979/security0/lulzsec-s-sony-hack-shows-rampant-password-re-use.html) that they are *not* capable of doing this. Additional examples abound.

Comment: @NecXelos I strongly believe that some people are stupid enough to do that *everywhere* and then expect people to fix it for them when their bank accounts get emptied.

Comment: Nec: passwords are evil. And realistically, you don't want someone impersonating you *anywhere* if there's even the slightest chance they could use that toe-hold to gain access to higher value accounts. Use Google with 2-factor if you can.